# Published Web files, can they be converted back to solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, publishing

Is it possible to take a set of published web files and convert them back into a solution? I say this because a solution has been lost from our system, and the only files that can be found are the actual published files. I have looked around and can't seem to find anything on the matter, any help would be great!

Thanks a lot

Comment: This entirely depends on exactly _how_ the project was published.

Comment: @GrantThomas It was just through the .NET 'Publish Solution' from right clicking the solution.

Comment: Was the original project a Web Application or a Website?

Comment: @FastGeek It is a Web Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Web Application the source code is compiled into DLL's. As far as I know there is no easy way to reverse engineer a Web Application back to source code. If you wish to do further research, use search terms such 'reverse engineer web application DLL', or 'retrieve source code from DLL' etc. Good luck!

Comment: dotPeek by JetBrains decompiles DLLs into source quite quickly and accurately. I've used it a few times and was quite pleased.
There might be other decompilers out there as well